# remove the month and date from a dynamic date field

Tags: c#, datetime

I am dynamically pulling in a a date field from my soql statement.

in my repeater i am getting the closeDate value.

my thought i would just pull the year in my set:

currently i am pulling data like: "2019-12-31" and i just want to display "2019"

```
private String closedateyear;
public String CloseDateYear 
{
    get { return closedateyear; }
    set
    {
        //pull year
    }
}
```

from what i read something like this may work:

```
string myDate = "05/11/2010"; 
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
int year = date.Year;
```

but when i implement it displays null

any help or guidance is appreciated

Comment: Did you remember to set `closedateyear = year.ToString()`?

Comment: Are you pulling the date as a datetime object or as a string? If you are getting it as a string, you can just get the first four characters using substring given that the format will not change. If you are getting it as a datetime object, just do date.Year.ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was i was pulling null  value for closedateyear on set.
Once i set the value closedateyear = value; everything after worked:

```
private String closedateyear;
public String CloseDateYear
{
    get { return closedateyear; }
    set
    {
        closedateyear = value;
         //retrieving data "2019-12-31"
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(closedateyear);
         //convert closedateyear to date time: similar to: "12/31/2019 12:00:00 AM"
        int year = date.Year;
         //extracting year: "2019"
        closedateyear = year.ToString();
         //set closedateyear = year value "12/31/2019 12:00:00 AM"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from string to date time works easier with [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8) or [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8)

So, you could try this:

```
string year = DateTime.Parse("2019-12-31").Year.ToString();
```